# Клавиатура обрезает модальное окно на мобильном устройстве?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет, на мобильном устройстве когда нажимаю на input - клавиатура "режет" белый фон на модалке. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Линк на репозиторий - 
arinaunderdoggit.github.io

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых используйте overflow-y , чтобы можно было прокрутить контент при включенной клавиатуре. Во-вторых, используйте padding у элемента в котором режется белый фон, видно у вас попросту нет прокрутки и он пытается сжать контент, меняя высоту. И третий момент, при создании вопроса, будьте добры вставить фрагмент вашего кода, чтобы хоть немного понимать какие стили вы используете, это существенно упростит выдачу ответа, нежели лезть на гит.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что суммарная высота элементов при активации input превосходит указанную Вами высоту для родительского блока .call-modal

Увидеть это можно, добавив к .call-modal

```
overflow: auto;
```

Обратите внимание, что у Вас:

1. На мобильных устройствах высота родительского блока в %, но при этом высота кнопки фиксированная.
2. Высота не включает толщину границ вокруг элемента, значение отступов и полей. (у вас при активации input высота содержимого увеличивается, в связи с чем и возникает проблема. Поиграйте с псевдоклассами (focus, active))